# Push Notifications Failed to send message. Status code: 500

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to arrange Firebase push notifications within a Flutter application with a Node.js server.

I wrote code based on this Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image#node.js

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

       const receivedToken = body.req.token;

       const androidMessage = {
         notification: {
           title: 'Sparky says hello!'
         },
         android: {
           notification: {
             imageUrl: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         apns: {
           payload: {
             aps: {
               'mutable-content': 1
             }
           },
           fcm_options: {
             image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         webpush: {
           headers: {
             image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         topic: topicName,
         token: receivedToken,
       };

       const iOSMessage = {
         notification: {
           title: 'Sparky says hello!'
         },
         android: {
           notification: {
             imageUrl: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         apns: {
           payload: {
             aps: {
               'mutable-content': 1
             }
           },
           fcm_options: {
             image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         webpush: {
           headers: {
             image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
           }
         },
         topic: topicName,
         token: receivedToken,
       };

      getMessaging().send(androidMessage)
        .then((response) => {
          // Response is a message ID string.
          console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });

  });
```

In Flutter I set call to Cloud Functions where the sendMessageA method was set up:

```js
Future<void> draftMessageA() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://us-central1-december2023.cloudfunctions.net/sendMessage'),
          body: {
            'token': fcmToken2,
            'deviceSystem': deviceSystem2,
            'title': title2,
            'body': body2,
            'category': 'manual entry',
            'sound': 'manual entry',
          });
      responseStatus = response.statusCode;
      theResponse = await response.body;
      print(theResponse);

      if (responseStatus == 200) {
        // Request was successful
        print('Message sent successfully');
      } else {
        // Handle other status codes
        print('Failed to send message. Status code: ${responseStatus}');
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }
```

After setting up Firebase Messaging, I receive confirmations that a token has been generated as well as the permission-status for notifications to be sent/received.

After triggering the cloud function I expected a push notification to have been produced and shown, but instead an internal server error status 500 is confirmed.

```css
D/FirebaseAuth(11767): Notifying id token listeners about user ( *************** ).
I/flutter (11767): FCM-Token set: [ ... ]
I/flutter (11767): Permission-to-notify = AuthorizationStatus.authorized
```

I am uncertain of what's going wrong and I suspect that there's more to be done than I have so far.

My question is, why am I receiving the internal server error instead of the push notification that I expected?

Your guidance towards making push notifications work within Flutter will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.